# SELECT query returns more records than exists

Tags: postgresql, postgis

**Background**

1. I have a table with raster data (grib_data) created by using `raster2pgsql`.
2. I have created a second table (turb_mod) with a subset of the points in grib_data that has a value above a certain threshold.
3. This subset table (turb_mod) has been created with the following query

   WITH turb AS (SELECT rid, rast, (ST_PixelAsPoints(rast)).val AS val
   FROM grib_data
   )
   SELECT rid, rast INTO turb_mod
   FROM turb WHERE val > 0.5;
4. The response when creating the table is "SELECT 53" indicating that the table turb_mod would now hold 53 rows

**Problem**

1. If I now try to return the raster data from turb_mod using the below query it returns all records from the original table, not the 53 that I am expecting

SELECT (ST_PixelAsPoints(rast)).x AS x FROM turb_mod;

**Questions**

1. Why does my query not return only the 53 records?
2. Is there a better way to create a table with a selection of raster points from the original table? I want to use the subset to apply further geospatial functions like spatial clustering.

Comment: What if you execute `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM turb_mod`?

Comment: To answer your second point, I'd suggest `cross apply` in SQL server, the postgres equivalent apparently being a `lateral join`.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie thank you for replying. The count returns as follows, which makes it even more baffling:


raster_test=# SELECT count(*) FROM turb_mod;
 count 
-------
    53
(1 row)

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here, to be honest, but it appears that `ST_PixelAsPoints` might return more than one row (the output is `setof record`)- is that what's happening? Ref: https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsPoints.html. `rast` is a raster band of potentially many pixels, am I right?

Comment: Also, the example in the link above looks like it probably answers your second point too...

Comment: I am also out of my depth, apparently ;-) But yes I believe you pointed me in the right direction. I think I have inserted the full raster 53 times, not only the points from the original query.

Comment: I've written up an answer to your question, for posterity :)

Answer (score 0):

In your final `SELECT`, you're calling the function `ST_PixelAsPoints`, which is a set-returning function. This results in *an output row [being] generated for each element of the function's result set* ([reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET)), and can thus result in a different row count to that of your source table, `turb_mod`.

Your query is functionally equivalent to this (preferred) syntax:

```sql
SELECT points.x
FROM
    turb_mod
    JOIN LATERAL ST_PixelAsPoints(rast) points ON TRUE;
```

This syntax better shows what's happening, and also shows how you might choose to include more columns from the function's output, which may help to answer your second point.